# eso-pic background tikz picture offset

Tags: tikz-pgf, eso-pic

I try to place bacground tikz image in document using eso-pic. I think that the reference point is the lower left corner. But in fact there is "X bias" in the 0.15 cm. Is it software or hardvare dependent? Will it present on others configurations or machines?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\begin{document}
  \AddToShipoutPicture{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (20,20);
  \end{tikzpicture}}

Some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Start by checking if ` \AddToShipoutPicture{%` makes a difference (untested)

Comment: Thanks for the replay. \AddToShipoutPicture{% works indeed. I'm beginer in LaTex so don't see difference between this sintax so will understand more.

Comment: It is a socalled spurious space, aka a space that is not ignored. It is one of the first things to check for in cases like this.

Comment: A newline character is interpreted by TeX as a space unless commented out.

Comment: @daleif An answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `\AddToShipoutPicture{%`, the `%` at the end will keep the tikz picture from shifting to the right because the space is not ignored.